# Output network speed in mbit/s using netcat

Tags: bash, netcat

I'm using netcat piped thorugh pv to measure network speed

Server A

```
netcat -l -q -1 -p 1234 | pv > /dev/null
```

Server B

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=10M count=1 | nc -v -n 10.10.10.2 1234
```

Result is returned on server B as

```
(UNKNOWN) [10.10.10.2] 1234 (?) open
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 5.24922 s, 2.0 MB/s
```

What I need to do is convert MB/s to Mbit/s and output that so in script I can do

```
echo $speed
16 Mbits/sec
```

Also I need netcat to always be listengin on Server A and not close after the transfer has completed. I've tries the -k and -q -1 switches but no luck.

Comment: to go from MB to Mb, you would take the number in Megabytes and multiply by 8.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the syntax to do this? I would use `awk`

Comment: yes I need the syntax to do this calculation

Comment: You could use `awk`. So lets say you pull the MB data into a variable. Example `speed="10MB"`. You could then do `awk \`{ printf ("%.3f\n"), '${speed}' * 8 }'`

Comment: Or even simpler:
`speed=10MB` then all you need to do is `echo $((${speed/MB} * 8))`

Comment: I am assuming that you are assigning the MB returned to a variable already.

Comment: `command substitution: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `"%.3f\n"'
/tmp/spd: command substitution: line 6: `{ printf ("%.3f\n"), '${speed}' * 8 }''`

Comment: `* 8: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* 8")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103262/discussion-between-lurch-and-bluerojo).

Comment: Cant continue in chat, sorry. What is the full command you are using

Comment: use the second one I gave you, it is simpler. the echo $(()) one